# Custom Convert Quote to Order - "Cannot retrieve payment method instance"

Tags: payment, quote

I have seen on occasion the case where an order is placed, an authorization is made for payment on the customer card, the *customer receives an order confirmation email* - but **no order exists** in Magento's `sales_flat_order` or `sales_flat_order_grid`.

The weapon of choice here is to require admin to void the payment in the gateway, ask customer to re-place.

However, we have all quote, quote items, quote payment, quote address. **In theory** this order is valid, after all, we have authorization and the customer has an order email. The error happened sometime after the order email generation that caused a rollback (the current working theory).

I have created a test one-off script to convert this quote using a sandbox gateway . However, I'm having trouble at generating the payment. I've tried to use `checkmo`, `free`, `authorizenet`, all return the same exception:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Cannot retrieve payment method instance.' in /var/www/vhosts/magento/app/Mage.php:563
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Info.php(83): Mage::throwException('Cannot retrieve...')
```

**See my code below**. Feedback welcomed.

```
<?php
//.... stuff

$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load(745);

$convert = Mage::getModel('sales/convert_quote');

$order = $convert->toOrder($quote);
$order->addressToOrder($quote->getAddress(),$order);

foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item){
    $orderItem = $convert->itemToOrderItem($item);
    if ($item->getParentItem()) {
       $orderItem->setParentItem($order->getItemByQuoteItemId($item->getParentItem()->getId()));
    }
    $order->addItem($orderItem);
}

$data = array(
        'method' => 'authorizenet',
        'cc_type' => 'VI',
        'cc_number' => '4111111111111111',
        'cc_exp_month' => '1',
        'cc_exp_year' => (date('Y') + 6),
        'cc_cid' => '444'
);

$quote->getShippingAddress()->setPaymentMethod('authorizenet');
$quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);

$payment = $quote->getPayment();
$payment->importData($data);
$quote->save();

$payment = $convert->paymentToOrderPayment($quote->getPayment());

$order->setPayment($quote->getPayment());

$message = '[Notice] - Order converted from quote manually';
$order->addStatusToHistory($order->getStatus(), $message);
$order->place();
$order->save();

$quote->setIsActive(false)->save();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are sending the order

```
 $quote->getPayment()
```

your code should look like this

```
...

$payment = $convert->paymentToOrderPayment($quote->getPayment());

$order->setPayment($payment);

...
```

Comment: You're right - that was it. Good call.

Comment: I am getting error `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'The requested Payment Method is not available.' in /var/www/html/app/Mage.php:594` I have enabled payment method as Purchase orderand want to create new order with zero cost without payment method.