# Copy an order to create a new order

Tags: orders

I want to create a new order from an existing order (customer address, cart products...etc) with a button "copy", Is it possible ?

Edit :

1) Imagine you have :

Order n°10001
Customer name : Magento, email : magento@magento.fr ...etc
Customer products : computer ASUS , speakers...

Now you want to have exactly the same order with the same customer and the same products BUT with a different n° of order :

Order n°10002
Customer name : Magento, email : magento@magento.fr ...etc
Customer products : computer ASUS , speakers...

So, first question : Is it possible ?

2) If yes, how can i do this ? i just don't know how to begin to do this in fact...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's already a built in feature. The button is called "reorder" and you will find it next to each order in the customer account

Comment: A working week for this... that's my first magento project, i feel so stupid right now... but thank you a lot, you save me :)

Comment: But it doesn't copy the status?

Comment: No, should it? The title states "new order". Otherwise I agree that it sounds like a broken process.

Answer (score 1):

Check the code in the backend for editing orders. When you edit an order, magento cancels the old one and creates a new one.

1. [Create quote from order](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/4699/217)
2. [Create order from quote](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3361/custom-convert-quote-to-order-cannot-retrieve-payment-method-instance)

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be what i needed but it's very complicated to just "copy" an order in the backoffice... + my customer wants to create an order from an order with "complete" status. I think it's just impossible ?

Comment: Sounds like a broken process. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I agree with you. My customer has some strange requests... He wants to create a new order which would be a copy of a "complete" order and then he could update the cart products or change address ... Edit : I change "complete" to "processing" in database for an order and something happened but there were some troubles (the products disappear...)

Answer (score 0):

I found a very good example which create a quote and convert it to an order. It could help some of you : https://sohelrana09.wordpress.com/2011/09/15/trouble-creating-a-quoteorder-through-custom-code-programmatically-create-order-without-use-api/#comment-451