# How to Programmatically Reorder in Magento 1.x in from Admin

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, module, orders

I want to create a custom module which creates duplicate order from the existing order.

I want to show a simple button (like Reorder default Magento) which create current order duplicate order in Magento.

Now I have created a simple script like below -

[as per this tutorial](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3361/custom-convert-quote-to-order-cannot-retrieve-payment-method-instance)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
set_time_limit(0);
require_once '/var/www/html/app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');

$order_id = 1200001726;
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_id);
$payment = $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle();
echo "\nPayment Method - ". $payment;

$quote_id = $order->getQuoteId();
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quote_id);
$convert = Mage::getModel('sales/convert_quote');
$order = $convert->toOrder($quote);
$order->addressToOrder($quote->getAddress(),$order);

foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item){
    $orderItem = $convert->itemToOrderItem($item);
    if ($item->getParentItem()) {
       $orderItem->setParentItem($order->getItemByQuoteItemId($item->getParentItem()->getId()));
    }
    $order->addItem($orderItem);
}

$quote->getShippingAddress()->setPaymentMethod('free');
$quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);

//$payment = $quote->getPayment();
$payment = $convert->paymentToOrderPayment($quote->getPayment());
//$payment->importData($data);
$payment->importData(array('method' => 'free'));
$quote->save();

$payment = $convert->paymentToOrderPayment($quote->getPayment());
$order->setPayment($payment);

$message = '[Notice] - Order converted from quote manually';
$order->addStatusToHistory($order->getStatus(), $message);
$order->place();
$order->save();

$quote->setIsActive(false)->save();

echo 'New Order '.$order->getIncrementId().' Create Successfully';


?>
```

It is showing below error. I have enabled Payment method as free for this store still it is showing this error.

> **PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' witthe h message 'The requested Payment Method is not available.' in
>   /var/www/html/app/Mage.php:594**

Please let me know if any suggestions.

New Code -

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
set_time_limit(0);
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');

class PlaceOrder
{
    public function place()
    {
        $orderId = 1200001816;
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
        $payment = $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle();
        echo "\nPayment Method - ". $payment;

        $quote = $this->createQuote($order);
        echo "\nQuote id - ". $quote->getId();

        $quote->getPayment()->setMethod('free');
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
        $quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);
        $quote->collectTotals();
        $quote->save();

        // set billing address
        $orderBillingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
        $quoteBillingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress();

        $quoteBillingAddress->setCustomerAddressId('');

        Mage::helper('core')->copyFieldset(
            'sales_copy_order_billing_address',
            'to_order',
            $orderBillingAddress,
            $quoteBillingAddress
        );

        //if (!$quote->isVirtual()) {
            // set shipping address
            $orderShippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();
            $quoteShippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();

            $quoteShippingAddress->setCustomerAddressId('')
                ->setSameAsBilling($orderShippingAddress && $orderShippingAddress->getSameAsBilling());

            Mage::helper('core')->copyFieldset(
                'sales_copy_order_shipping_address',
                'to_order',
                $orderShippingAddress,
                $quoteShippingAddress
            );

            // Make collect rates when user click "Get shipping methods and rates" in order creating
            $quoteShippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true);
            $quoteShippingAddress->collectShippingRates();

            // Set shipping method from order
            $quoteShippingAddress->setShippingMethod($order->getShippingMethod());
            $quoteShippingAddress->setShippingDescription($order->getShippingDescription());

            // Set shipping method others
            //$quoteShippingAddress->setShippingMethod('Free');
            //$quoteShippingAddress->setShippingRate(0);
            //$quoteShippingAddress->setShippingDescription('TEST DESC');
        //}

        $quote->collectTotals();
        $quote->save();

        //$service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
        $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $this->_quote);

        $service->submitAll();
        $order = $service->getOrder();

        $message = '[Notice] - Order converted from quote manually';
        $order->addStatusToHistory($order->getStatus(), $message);
        $order->save();

        echo 'New Order '.$order->getIncrementId().' Create Successfully';
    }

    /**
     * @param Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Quote
     */
    public function createQuote($order)
    {
        // prepare empty quote for the customer
        $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
        $customer = $this->getCustomer($order);
        $quote->setStoreId($order->getStoreId())
            ->setCustomerGroupId($customer->getGroupId())
            ->assignCustomer($customer)
            ->setIsActive(false)
            ->save();

        $quote->setIgnoreOldQty(true);
        $quote->setIsSuperMode(true);
        $storeId = $order->getStoreId();
        foreach ($order->getItemsCollection(
            array_keys(Mage::getConfig()->getNode('adminhtml/sales/order/create/available_product_types')->asArray()),
            true
        ) as $orderItem) {
            /* @var $orderItem Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item */
            if (!$orderItem->getParentItem()) {
                if ($order->getReordered()) {
                    $qty = $orderItem->getQtyOrdered();
                } else {
                    $qty = $orderItem->getQtyOrdered() - $orderItem->getQtyShipped() - $orderItem->getQtyInvoiced();
                }

                if ($qty > 0) {
                    $item = $this->initFromOrderItem($quote, $storeId, $orderItem, $qty);
                    if (is_string($item)) {
                        Mage::throwException($item);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $quote;
    }

    /**
     * @param Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order
     * @return Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
     */
    public function getCustomer($order)
    {
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
        if ($order->getStore()) {
            $customer->setStore($order->getStore());
        }
        if ($customerId = $order->getCustomerId()) {
            $customer->load($customerId);
        }

        return $customer;
    }

    /**
     * Initialize creation data from existing order Item
     *
     * @param Mage_Sales_Model_Quote $quote
     * @param int $storeId
     * @param Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item $orderItem
     * @param int $qty
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item|string
     */
    public function initFromOrderItem($quote, $storeId, $orderItem, $qty = null)
    {
        if (!$orderItem->getId()) {
            return $this;
        }

        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->load($orderItem->getProductId());

        if ($product->getId()) {
            $product->setSkipCheckRequiredOption(true);
            $buyRequest = $orderItem->getBuyRequest();
            if (is_numeric($qty)) {
                $buyRequest->setQty($qty);
            }
            $item = $quote->addProduct($product, $buyRequest);
            if (is_string($item)) {
                return $item;
            }

            if ($additionalOptions = $orderItem->getProductOptionByCode('additional_options')) {
                $item->addOption(new Varien_Object(
                    array(
                        'product' => $item->getProduct(),
                        'code' => 'additional_options',
                        'value' => serialize($additionalOptions)
                    )
                ));
            }

            return $item;
        }

        return $this;
    }
}

$placeObj = new PlaceOrder();
$placeObj->place();

?>
```

**Quote.php**

```
<?php

class TM_FireCheckout_Model_Service_Quote extends Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote
{
    // removed address validation
    protected function _validate()
    {
        $helper = Mage::helper('sales');
        if (!$this->getQuote()->isVirtual()) {

            Mage::logException(new Exception("Check 1")); 
            /*if($this->getQuote()->isVirtual()){
                echo "value " . $this->getQuote()->isVirtual();
            }else{
                echo "value2 " . $this->getQuote()->isVirtual();
            }*/
            $address = $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
            $addressValidation = Mage::getSingleton('firecheckout/type_standard')->validateAddress($address);
            if ($addressValidation !== true) {
                Mage::throwException(
                    $helper->__('Please check shipping address information. %s', implode(' ', $addressValidation))
                );
            }
            $method = $address->getShippingMethod();
            $rate = $address->getShippingRateByCode($method);

            if(!$method){
                Mage::logException(new Exception("Empty shipping method.Rahul")); 
            }
            if(!$rate){
                Mage::logException(new Exception("Rate was empty inside quote validate method, trying to forcefully recalculate"));
                $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
                $this->getQuote()->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);
                $this->getQuote()->collectTotals();
                $rate  = $address->getShippingRateByCode($method);
            }
            if(!$this->getQuote()->isVirtual()){
                Mage::logException(new Exception("Empty isVirtual1"));
            }
            if (!$this->getQuote()->isVirtual() && (!$method || !$rate)) {
                Mage::logException(new Exception("Please specify a shipping method."));
            }
        }

        $addressValidation = Mage::getSingleton('firecheckout/type_standard')
            ->validateAddress($this->getQuote()->getBillingAddress());

        if ($addressValidation !== true) {
            Mage::throwException(
                $helper->__('Please check billing address information. %s', implode(' ', $addressValidation))
            );
        }

        if (!($this->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethod())) {
            Mage::throwException($helper->__('Please select a valid payment method.'));
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following script:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
set_time_limit(0);
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');

class PlaceOrder
{
    public function place()
    {
        $orderId = 145000021;
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
        $payment = $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle();
        echo "\nPayment Method - ". $payment;

        $quote = $this->createQuote($order);
        $quote->getPayment()->setMethod('free');
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
        $quote->collectTotals();
        $quote->save();

        // set billing address
        $orderBillingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
        $quoteBillingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress();

        $quoteBillingAddress->setCustomerAddressId('');

        Mage::helper('core')->copyFieldset(
            'sales_copy_order_billing_address',
            'to_order',
            $orderBillingAddress,
            $quoteBillingAddress
        );

        if (!$quote->isVirtual()) {
            // set shipping address
            $orderShippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();
            $quoteShippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();

            $quoteShippingAddress->setCustomerAddressId('')
                ->setSameAsBilling($orderShippingAddress && $orderShippingAddress->getSameAsBilling());

            Mage::helper('core')->copyFieldset(
                'sales_copy_order_shipping_address',
                'to_order',
                $orderShippingAddress,
                $quoteShippingAddress
            );

            // Make collect rates when user click "Get shipping methods and rates" in order creating
            $quoteShippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true);
            $quoteShippingAddress->collectShippingRates();

            // Set shipping method from order
            //$quoteShippingAddress->setShippingMethod($order->getShippingMethod());

            // Set shipping method others
            $quoteShippingAddress->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate');
            //$quoteShippingAddress->setShippingDescription($order->getShippingDescription());
            $quoteShippingAddress->setShippingDescription('TEST DESC');
        }

        $quote->collectTotals();
        $quote->save();

        $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
        $service->submitAll();
        $order = $service->getOrder();

        $message = '[Notice] - Order converted from quote manually';
        $order->addStatusToHistory($order->getStatus(), $message);
        $order->save();

        echo 'New Order '.$order->getIncrementId().' Create Successfully';
    }

    /**
     * @param Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Quote
     */
    public function createQuote($order)
    {
        // prepare empty quote for the customer
        $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
        $customer = $this->getCustomer($order);
        $quote->setStoreId($order->getStoreId())
            ->setCustomerGroupId($customer->getGroupId())
            ->assignCustomer($customer)
            ->setIsActive(false)
            ->save();

        $quote->setIgnoreOldQty(true);
        $quote->setIsSuperMode(true);
        $storeId = $order->getStoreId();
        foreach ($order->getItemsCollection(
            array_keys(Mage::getConfig()->getNode('adminhtml/sales/order/create/available_product_types')->asArray()),
            true
        ) as $orderItem) {
            /* @var $orderItem Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item */
            if (!$orderItem->getParentItem()) {
                if ($order->getReordered()) {
                    $qty = $orderItem->getQtyOrdered();
                } else {
                    $qty = $orderItem->getQtyOrdered() - $orderItem->getQtyShipped() - $orderItem->getQtyInvoiced();
                }

                if ($qty > 0) {
                    $item = $this->initFromOrderItem($quote, $storeId, $orderItem, $qty);
                    if (is_string($item)) {
                        Mage::throwException($item);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $quote;
    }

    /**
     * @param Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order
     * @return Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
     */
    public function getCustomer($order)
    {
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
        if ($order->getStore()) {
            $customer->setStore($order->getStore());
        }
        if ($customerId = $order->getCustomerId()) {
            $customer->load($customerId);
        }

        return $customer;
    }

    /**
     * Initialize creation data from existing order Item
     *
     * @param Mage_Sales_Model_Quote $quote
     * @param int $storeId
     * @param Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item $orderItem
     * @param int $qty
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item|string
     */
    public function initFromOrderItem($quote, $storeId, $orderItem, $qty = null)
    {
        if (!$orderItem->getId()) {
            return $this;
        }

        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->load($orderItem->getProductId());

        if ($product->getId()) {
            $product->setSkipCheckRequiredOption(true);
            $buyRequest = $orderItem->getBuyRequest();
            if (is_numeric($qty)) {
                $buyRequest->setQty($qty);
            }
            $item = $quote->addProduct($product, $buyRequest);
            if (is_string($item)) {
                return $item;
            }

            if ($additionalOptions = $orderItem->getProductOptionByCode('additional_options')) {
                $item->addOption(new Varien_Object(
                    array(
                        'product' => $item->getProduct(),
                        'code' => 'additional_options',
                        'value' => serialize($additionalOptions)
                    )
                ));
            }

            return $item;
        }

        return $this;
    }
}

$placeObj = new PlaceOrder();
$placeObj->place();
```

***This is working fine with Magento ver. 1.9.4.0***

Comment: I want reorder with zero grand total so I am using free payment method. I want all other items from previous order with customer details. How can I correct my script. I have tried your way but still I am bit confused. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try updated script

Comment: I am getting error `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Please specify a shipping method.' in /var/www/html/app/Mage.php:594` while creating order.

Comment: As per this question I have tried solution as well but not working. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7623/getting-a-please-specify-a-shipping-method-exception-during-checkout

Comment: What is your shipping method?

Comment: The source order shows ground shipping.

Comment: That means your USPS/DHL doesn't return this shipping. Try using flatrate shipping.

Comment: How can I set this new shipping method in above script. I tried to change in `/var/www/html/app/code/local/TM/FireCheckout/Model/Service/Quote.php` `if(!$method || !$rate){
                $method = 'flatrate_flatrate';
                $address->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates()->setShippingMethod($method);
            }` as per this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/251561/34929. However its not working as expected.

Comment: Actually $rate value is empty.

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: `$this->getQuote()->isVirtual()` and `$rate` value is empty which is throwing exception. How Can I Set value for this variable and which is valid value for this ?

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89963/discussion-between-rahul-and-sohel-rana).

Comment: I am getting $this->getQuote()->isVirtual() is empty or NULL value. I have recalcualte $rate. How can I fix this issue in /var/www/html/app/code/local/TM/FireCheckout/Model/Service/Quote.php

Comment: Did $this->getQuote() return actual quote?

Comment: Its creating new quote each time when above order creation code call. Do we need to load existing order quote instead of create new quote, but I have read somewhere that old quotes get deleted after some time. please suggest. Please check code in question as well.

Comment: I have recalculate $rate and fix that  Not having issue with  $this->getQuote()->isVirtual(). Please check Quote.php

Comment: $this->getQuote() is not getting quote actually. Its empty.

Comment: Sometimes this code is not working and throws exception. While adding items to new quote all the items are not getting added to new quote items .  New Question created with new loginc https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/266549/how-to-create-duplicate-new-quote-from-old-order-quote-magento-1-7